# PHP GET method is getting wrong data

Tags: php

I fill the next form:

```
 <form name="frmContacto" class="form-horizontal" method="GET" action="./mail/contact_me.php">
     <fieldset>
            <legend class="text-center header">Formulario de contacto</legend>

            <div class="form-group">
                <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i
                        class="fa fa-user bigicon"></i></span>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Nombre"
                           class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i
                        class="fa fa-envelope-o bigicon"></i></span>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Correo electrónico"
                           class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i
                        class="fa fa-phone-square bigicon"></i></span>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Teléfono"
                           class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i
                        class="fa fa-pencil-square-o bigicon"></i></span>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message"
                              placeholder="Introduce aquí tu mensaje." rows="7"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <a href="mailto:xxx@gmail.com?Subject=Hello%20again" target="_top">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Enviar</button>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

PHP side:

```
<?php

$name = isset($_GET['name']);
echo $name;
$email_address = isset($_GET['email']);
echo $email_address;
$phone = isset($_GET['phone']);
echo $phone;
$message = isset($_GET['message']);
echo $message;

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'xxx@gmail.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Formulario de contacto web:  $name";
$email_body = "Ha recibido un nuevo mensaje desde la web.\n\n" . "Detalles:\n\Nombre: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\Teléfono: $phone\n\Mensaje:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);
return true;
?>
```

I think GET method is getting wrong data, I fill the form with text strings, but the echo methods are printing 1:
[image]

If I fill the form with real strings, why is the echo method printing 1 for each field? Also, I think that the warning is because the parameters are all "1", but this make no sense for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have assigned the value of [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to the variable:

> Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL.

This will return `1` when the variable is set.

```
$name = isset($_GET['name']);
echo $name;
$email_address = isset($_GET['email']);
echo $email_address;
$phone = isset($_GET['phone']);
echo $phone;
$message = isset($_GET['message']);
echo $message;
```

The following code will check if the `$_GET` variable is set, then assign it:

```
if (isset($_GET['name'])) { $name = $_GET['name'];
echo $name;
}
if (isset($_GET['email'])) { $email_address = $_GET['email'];
echo $email_address;
}
if (isset($_GET['phone'])) { $phone = $_GET['phone'];
echo $phone;
}
if (isset($_GET['message'])) { $message = $_GET['message'];
echo $message;
}
```

Comment: To add to this answer, you can also use `$name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : false;`

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the return value of `isset()` and not the array index you are testinging to see if it is set.

> ```
> $name = isset($_GET['name']);
> ```

should be something more along the lines of:

```
$name = "";
if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
    $name = $_GET['name'])
};
```

or you could use a ternary operator:

```
$name = (isset($_GET['name'])) ? $_GET['name'] : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is there:

```
$name = isset($_GET['name']);
echo $name;
```

Because $_GET exists, `isset($_GET['name'])` returns 1, which you store in `$name`. `$name` is equal to 1 now (or `true`).

do something like

```
if(isset($_GET['name']))
{
   echo $_GET['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use like below:-

```
 if(isset($_GET['name']))
 {
 $name = $_GET['name'];
 }
```